# Why is string not escaped?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

Consider following example:

`string s = "this is formatted \" string \"";`

When i return this as plain string in my web api method:

`return Ok(s)`

it produces the following output

> this is formatted "string"

but if i return it as an Object

```
return Ok(new {
  myStr = s
})
```

it will not escape the string properly and return following output

```
{
    "myStr ": "this is formatted \" string \""
}
```

ideally i want

```
{
    "myStr ": "this is formatted " string "
}
```

I need the formatting for html string, the above example is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: The JSON formatters won't do that for you, nor should they. You'd need to create your string using something like [WebUtility.HtmlEncode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmlencode)

Comment: @TiesonT. Please check the edit.

Comment: What you want is an invalid JSON response, that's why the quotes are escaped

Comment: `"myStr ": "this is formatted " string "` is a malformed JSON property. You want it to be `"myStr ": "this is formatted \" string \""` so that when it is parsed the property has the value of `this is formatted " string "`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a string literal in source code (which JSON is!) then you need to use some delimiter so signal where the literal starts and ends. Often double quotes (`"`) are used for this.

But you run into a problem when the string literal should contain the same character as is used to delimit it. The solution is some form of *escaping*. In C#:

```
string s1 = "this is formatted \" string \".";
string s2 = @"this is formatted "" string "".";
```

Your single-string response doesn't need the delimiters, because only the contents of the string were sent. So there is no conflict, so no escaping needed.

Your JSON response has more information than just the string contents, so it needs to delimit those contents. Thus you get the delimiter-in-content issue that is solved by escaping.

An important point here is that that escaping is *only* in the source code (or JSON), the in-memory value of the string contains just that quote, no extra escaping characters. Try getting the length of the string value: the backslashes are not counted, because they aren't there really. Also when you *use* the string value (print it somewhere) you will not see that escaping.

A sidenote: a debugger, such as the one in Visual Studio, may show string contents in a format that you can use in source code - including required escaping. This is just the way that debugger *show* the value, not the *real* value.

Bottom line: you can ignore the escaping in that JSON, the correct value will be used.

Answer (score 1):

It is not problem, it is normal.

Because `string s = "this is formatted \" string \"";` is strongly typed string and you return one value from API. Therefore when it is serialized result will be `this is formatted "string"`, that it will not be stringfied.

But If you return object from API, like as below:

```
return Ok(new {
  myStr = s
})
```

Then result is json object, Therefore myStr will be stringfied string, because it is contains `"` symbol.

Because

1. if string start with `"`  (double quote), it doesn't contains another `"`, but it contains `\"` or `'` .
2. if string start with `'`  (single quote), it doesn't contains another `'`, but it contains `\'` or `"` .

[image]
You can look at :

1. [JavaScript Strings](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)
2. [The real difference between ‘single quotes’ and “double quotes” in JavaScript](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/the-real-difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-javascript-3d00bf720bcd)